# Creating user form Jenkins-cli, anyway to assign role too?

Tags: jenkins, command-line-interface, jenkins-cli

Hey I am creating user from jenkins-cli:

```
echo 'jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.securityRealm.createAccount("newuser", "123456")' | java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -auth admin:adminpass -s http://url:8080/ groovy =
```

This will create user but as it has no permission so user cant do nothing. What I am trying to do is to add it in a role to. like when user create it get add in a role `"devs"` too by command line

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on `Jenkins 2.204.2` with `Role-based Authorization Strategy 2.13`.

```sh
role=testRole
user=testUser

java -jar /var/jenkins_home/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ groovy = <<EOF

jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.securityRealm.createAccount("$user", "$user") 
com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy.getInstance().doAssignRole("globalRoles", "$role", "$user" )

EOF
```